# 2 Activities get notified on GPS Status Changed

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog, activity-stack, android-gps

I have `A Activity` and `B Activity`, both implement `LocationListener`. So both have

```
@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // Open AlertDialog
}
```

I start `B Activity` from `A Activity`. When i turn off GPS on `B`, it opens `AlertDialog` as shown on code, then i turn on GPS and dismiss `AlertDialog`. Now when i return back to `A Activity` it shows `AlertDialog` too because it get notified when GPS is turned off few seconds ago.

I think even i opened `B` from `A`, `A` is not destroyed completely and is saved on backstack. So how do i solve this problem without removing `A` from Activity Backstack **?** App should only open `AlertDialog` on whichever Activity is on the screen.

Comment: stop listening gps in Activity A's onPause or onStop method. and start listening in onResume.

Comment: @sourabhbans yes i was just trying that. Because i was stopping to listen on `onDestroy`

Comment: Ok that did trick, again i need to start to listen when i return back from `B`, and i did that too :) @sourabhbans you can write it on answer

Comment: yes... you should start listening in `onresume()`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stop listening gps in Activity A's onPause or onStop method. and start listening in onResume. 
like : in `A`

```
onStop(..){
// stop gps listening here
}
```

and again when return from B..

```
onResume(..){
// start gps listening here
}
```